# Xcode 4.1.1 : how to push an existing project (not yet under Git) onto a remote Git Server

Tags: git, xcode4

I just set myself up a Git server on Amazon, and I was trying to figure out how to push my projects onto it. The repo is setup in Organizer, green light. However, when i go to the version control menu, the 'push' menu is greyed out. Is there a way to bind a project to a remote server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup my git account with github, but I remember there being some initialization stuff that needs to be completed on your computer before you can import a project. Github's instructions look like they have some parts that are specific to github, but it may still help to look it over.

http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/

What Amazon product are you specifically using? EC2? S3?

Comment: EC2 backed frequently on S3 :) ... its an Ubuntu 9.04 box, git-core installed and running poifekt on there. I created a git account on the box, and will have my workstations peer with the repo setup in that account.

Comment: Well unfortunately I am not sure exactly what is going wrong, but maybe have a look at this page from apple. Go down to the "Keep Track of Changes with Source Control" section and check out what they say about setting up git in Xcode.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Comment: Thks for the link. The gist of it is 'no can do', you must do it manually, at the command line. I will later post a writeup on the nit-grit of doing this.